# Storing response from PHP Guzzle as JSON in database (Laravel)

Tags: php, json, guzzle

Im calling a vehicle data API at an endpoint and can return the data fine using:

```
$client = new Client();
$url = "https://uk1.ukvehicledata.co.uk/api/MISC DETAILS;
$result = $client->get($url);

return $result->request;
```

This is using mock data so the response is:

```
{
    "Request":{
        "RequestGuid":"",
        "PackageId":""
    "Response":{
        // VEHICLE DATA
    }
}
```

However, I now wish to store the response in the database but cannot access ->request or ->Request etc.

Using:

```
return json_encode( (array)$result );
```

Actually returns the headers from Guzzle and no response data.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the body into JSON first:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($result->getBody()->getContents(), true);

echo $jsonArray['Request']['RequestGuid'];
```